# Class based DetailView dynamically choose template

Tags: django, django-views

This must be quite simple, but I simply can not wrap my head around it.
I have the following code:

*models.py*

```
class Template(models.Model):
    ...
    display_type = models.CharField(max_length="20", choices=DISPLAYTYPE)
    ...

class Display(models.Model):
    ...
    template = models.ForeignKey(Template)
```

*views.py*

```
class DisplayDetail(DetailView):
    model = Display
    template_name = 'kiosk/display_detail.html'
    ...

class HDMIDisplay(DisplayDetail):
    def get_object(self):
        object = super(DisplayDetail, self).get_object()
        object['template'] = object.template.display_type
        return object

    if template == "static":
        template_name = 'kiosk/HDMI-static.html'
    elif template == "list":
        template_name = 'kiosk/HDMI-list.html'
    else:
        template_name = 'kiosk/HDMI-slideshow.html'
```

Now, I know that this is not going to work the way it is written right now, but what I need is how to get the template value from the model into the view, to be able to build my condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your view class should look like following:

```
class HDMIDisplay(DisplayDetail):

    def get_template_names(self):
        return [self.object.template.display_type]
```

also you need to specify full path to templates in your display choices (in models.py) i.e:

```
DISPLAYTYPE = (
    ('kiosk/static.html', 'Static'),
    ('kiosk/list.html', 'List'),
    ('kiosk/default.html', 'Default'),
```

I tested it, so this will enough to solve your problem

Comment: More on [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin.template_name_field)